# Regex to find date format

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a dataframe with column `Date`. It contains values like `2022-01-03`.

I want to create a new df with only those rows that fulfil the conditions:

- starting with `20`
- `-` signs between the four-digit year and the two-digit month and then between the two-digit month and two-digit day

The below doesn't work:

`df2 = my_df.where('Date like "20\d\d-\d\d-\d\d"')`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You may use `rlike()` here:

```
df2 = my_df.filter(col("Date").rlike("20[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}"))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've spent quite a bit of time googling the solution. Do you have an idea why "\d" doesn't work?

Comment: @BigMadAndy I also avoided using `\d` because I wasn't sure if `\d` (one backslash) or `\\d` (two backslashes) is required.